# Do apex:actionfunction calls count against the API Requests limit?

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

I have a Visualforce page containing a table of `<apex:inputfield>` elements. Each time a field is updated (`onchange`) an `<apex:actionfunction>` updates the record using an Apex call.

Should I be concerned about reaching any limits with this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, apex within your organization does not count against API calls. The only limits that apply here are apex limits, and those are documented in detail here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

Generally speaking, it's not usually a limits issue when you're dealing with a DML on one record. That said, you could invoke complex apex code affecting many records, performing many calculations, or have a host of chained triggers that fire a bunch of code updating thousands of records, in which case, limits would be a concern. It all depends on what you apex code does.

It's possible to do a callout from apex to your own organization (I've seen this for accessing the Chatter API, for example) and that callout would count against your API calls.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Javascript Remoting also counts against the limit, too. Just wanted to check if Action Functions did as well, because they're similar. Thanks!

Comment: Javascript remoting does not count as an API call either.

Comment: Ah, this is where I was confused: if the method is exposed as a `webservice` as well as a `@RemoteAction`, calling it using JavaScript remoting does count against the API limit.

Comment: I have been running some javascript remoting in my sandbox and it does seem to be increasing the api usage count? Do you know if it actually does count or not